# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\right)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I find the following limit :$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{10}\right)^2\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\right)^2$$There are four options $(a)\frac1{3}(b)\frac1{9}(c)\frac1{81}(d)0$
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1-\frac{2}{n(n+1)}=\frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{n(n+1)}$$

In the following equation, you can simplify $(i+1)$ with the next $i$, except for the first (that is equals to $1$ anyway), and $(i+3)$ with the next $(i+2)$ except for the first one (that is equals to $3$)

$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{(i+1)(i+2)}\right)^2=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{i(i+3)}{(i+1)(i+2)}\right)^2=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{i+3}{i+2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{3^2}$$

Note that we proved in fact that 
$$ \prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{2}{(i+1)(i+2)}\right)^2=\left(\frac{n+3}{3(n+1)}\right)^2$$

So the answer is $(b)$